# Exception raised during rendering in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout, exception, rendering, android-theme

I have an error in Android xml layout as follows :

```
Exception raised during rendering: <include /> can only be used inside of a ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Now, When I am changing the AppTheme to Theme.Holo than its working fine.
I want to know that Why is it like this ?